# How to highlight duplicate values based on values in single cell through VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have six columns like name, assignment, Group, Role, Geo and ID and I want to highlight the duplicate values within the same ID based on the cell values. The cell has multiple values with a semicolon. if any cell values match with the other cell values, it should highlight both rows.

[Raw file view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBPfm.jpg)
[Result view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG0IS.jpg)

I have written a macro for it but it doesn't work.
Please assist.

```
    Sub DuplTTM()
    'select first row data and compare with the table
     Dim i As Long, j As Long, nextrow As Long, lastrow As Long, nwsheet As Worksheet, r As Integer, 
    c1 As Integer, c2 As Integer, c3 As Integer

    ' sorting data by ID

    Columns("A:F").Sort key1:=Range("F2"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

   ' finding the last row
   lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   'random colour generation
   c1 = Int(255 * Rnd) + 1
   c2 = Int(255 * Rnd) + 1
   c3 = Int(255 * Rnd) + 1
   mycolor = RGB(c1, c2, c3)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  j = 3
   ' defining next row with expected result
  For i = 2 To lastrow

  arrv = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3), "; ")
   arrn = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 3), "; ")

 If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 6).Value Then
        For Each k In arrv
            For Each l In arrn
        If (Trim(k) = Trim(l)) = True Then
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value <> ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 6).Interior.Color = mycolor
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(1, 6).Interior.Color = mycolor
            Exit For
            End If
        End If
            Next l
        Next k
End If
j = j + 1
  Next i

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Completed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to So.. Conditional formatting can do this. with formula =Countif("IDColumn","ID")>1.. You will need to appy this to one row. And then copy format to other rows

Comment: Or you can select all the range and apply it at once. But keep the ID column fixed in the formula and id relative.

Comment: Apparently my answer was of no help. Hence I removed it. Hopefully someone else is able to help you.